# Getting Sql Error while Adding batch to the prepared statement for oracle driver

Tags: oracle, prepared-statement

I am getting `SQLException` while adding the second statement to the batch in the `PreparedStatement` with Oracle JDBC driver.

```
java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: DML Returning cannot be batched
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.addBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9800)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.addBatch(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:998)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.addBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
```

Here is my code:

```java
query="insert into case_number__v(uid__v   , worldwide_uid__v  ) values (?,?)";
ps = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

//int parameterCount=1;
List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
data.add(new Object[]{"John Doe", "johndoe@example.com"});
data.add(new Object[]{"Jane Smith", "janesmith@example.com"});
data.add(new Object[]{"Bob Johnson", "bobjohnson@example.com"});
for (Object[] row : data) {
    ps.setString(1, (String) row[0]);
    ps.setString(2, (String) row[1]);

    // Add the PreparedStatement object to the batch
    ps.addBatch();
}

// Execute the batch and retrieve the generated ids
int[] counts = ps.executeBatch();
ResultSet rs1 = ps.getGeneratedKeys();

// Loop through the ResultSet object to retrieve the generated ids
while (rs1.next()) {
    System.out.println("Generated id: " + rs1.getLong(1));
}
System.out.println(counts.length + " rows inserted successfully.");
```

And while adding the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`, only then it is showing the above error. If not, then I don't get generated ids. For MySQL and PL/SQL the same `PreparedStatement` is working properly but for Oracle only I am getting this error. I am using:

```
<groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
```

My requirement is to use batch insert and I need to get the generated IDs. Is there any other way for Oracle to get generated IDs? Please mention your suggestions that will really help me.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem appears to be with your SQL statement. From the code in your question, I believe that the variable named `query` holds the SQL statement. I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the actual SQL statement that you are trying to execute via the `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: You might want to try using a newer driver. As of [12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28099) the limitations said you couldn't use batch; as of [12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/JDBC-standards-support.html#GUID-1C2E2B0F-081B-4AC2-84EB-91B1D84E5C3F) they don't; 19c is the same. The [version compatibility matrix](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-926E5324-D89A-4A00-B1AE-975C1089F0EA) might be useful too.